# "fatal: remote origin already exists" with nested git repository folders

Tags: git

I have a folder inside a git repository which should be its own repository.

I do not want to use the git submodules or whatever they provide.

I have done this multiple times before and it always worked but now there seems to be something wrong.

Inside the nested folder I do this:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/team/repo
```

and I get this:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I think whats happening is that it recognised the git repository thats one folder above and therefore isnt allowing me to set one up in it. But I KNOW that I have done this before and its working with the other folders. When I do "git status" in the working ones I get a status that shows the sub repo and not the overlying one.

What can I do to tell git to ignore the top one and pretend like its not there?

EDIT: Here is what DOES work:

Instead of creating the folder and doing `git remote add origin ...` I straight away just clone the existing repo. Then I end up with a working subfolder with its own origin. (Am I already using submodules now or is this in fact a work around?)

EDIT2: This question is about HOW to solve the nesting problem. The possible duplicate however is about WHY the solution found in the anwsers works the way it does.

Comment: "I have done this multiple times before and it always worked but now there seems to be something wrong."
How? And submodules,subtrees or symlinks are the usual and for the most part intended way to do exactly that.
For your errer: You are in a git repository. remote has list of handles (the default being `origin`) where you can add urls my specifying new handles, however, you cannot overwrite old ones. Also if you would do that you would have to delete the url for origin in your repository (which has root in .. according to you)

Comment: Okay so heres the difference from what I did before. Before I did `git clone someprobablyemptyrepo` and the resulting sub folder is a folder with the seperate repo which lies inside the above one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I do "git clone repo" inside an existing repo but not "git remote add origin repo" inside subfolder in an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520746/why-can-i-do-git-clone-repo-inside-an-existing-repo-but-not-git-remote-add-or)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to having nested repo's like I described is either just cloning the wanted repo inside the other *or* creating the folder, navigating inside and running both `git init` as well as `git remote add origin`.

The latter wont work without `git init`