# Why can I do "git clone repo" inside an existing repo but not "git remote add origin repo" inside subfolder in an existing repo?

Tags: git

This question stems from a previous one where I was trying to make a repository out of a subfolder inside an already existing repository.

When I created the folder and ran "git remote add origin ..." inside it I got the following error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

But, when I cd back into the previous folder and run:

```
git clone someNewRepo
```

it works flawlessly and I am able to work with that repository seperately.

My question is, am I using git submodules now or is this a work around that shouldnt actually work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to `git init` a new sub-repository before `git remote add` to get the same behaviour as `git clone`. If you do that, it works as expected.

Comment: So am I unknowingly tapping into gits subrepo functionality or does that just work by chance?

Comment: Your comment is unclear to me. Does _what_ work by chance?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude there is no submodule in sight so far, but Git allows you to nest repositories. Performing a command acts on the closest parent repository.

Comment: @Quentin "Performing a command acts on the closest parent repository" That clears it up!